# Jquery's eq(0), "..first-child", first() not grabbing first child if its an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, css-selectors

Basically I need to grab the first child of a parent element, usually but not limited to an `<iframe>`.

```
<div> 
    <iframe src="www.asource.com">GRAB THIS AFTER A BUTTON IS CLICKED</iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried the following

```
   $("#parent").eq(0).prop("tagName");
    $("#parent").first().prop("tagName");
    $("#parent:first").prop("tagName");
    $("#parent:nth-child(1)").prop("tagName");
    $("#parent:lt(1)").prop("tagName");
```

All of these return a "div" when I alert them. The reason I am getting the prop name was because I wanted to use the find() to get the element.

```
 $("parent").find(ONE OF THE PROP CALLS ABOVE).animate({.....
```

because when I do:

```
 $("parent").find('**iframe**').animate({.....
```

**that is the only scenario that I can grab and properly animate an *iframe***. 
however since we don't know if the first child is an iframe or not, i used .prop() to get the first element tag name and find it. 
(please note, i tried all the above attempts directly with .animate(...) instead of .prop(...) but that also didn't grab the iframe. 
Would really appreciate some guidance

Comment: What is "#parent"? I see no element with the id parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need find the first child so

```
$("#parent").children().first().prop("tagName");
$("#parent > :first-child").prop("tagName");
$("#parent > :eq(0)").prop("tagName");
```

Assuming you are using the correct parent selector - the above code assumes the parent element has the id `parent` like

```
<div id="parent"> 
    <iframe src="www.asource.com">GRAB THIS AFTER A BUTTON IS CLICKED</iframe>
</div>
```